# offset joining of datasets in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

There is data

```
data1=structure(list(y1 = c(3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 5L), y2 = c(5L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 5L)), .Names = c("y1", "y2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

It is two variables(y1,y2).

```
y1  y2
3   5
5   7
6   8
7   9
5   5
```

in fact there are 5 lines

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

There is another dataset

```
data2=structure(list(v1 = 1:2, v2 = c(1L, 3L), x = c(10L, 30L)), .Names = c("v1", 
"v2", "x"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

v1  v2  x
1   1   10
2   3   30
```

1,2 for v1 and 1,3 for v2 this is number of rows.
so first row of v1 and first row of v2 i must join to
first row of y1 and first row of y2

then
second row of v1 i must join with second row of y1 and third row of v2, i must join with 3 row of  y2

so output

```
y1  y2  v1  v2  x
3   5   1   1   10
5   8   2   3   30
```

If this post is duplicate, let me know, i'll delete it.

## let me edit post to be more clearly

data2

```
v1  v2
1   1
3   5
4   8
7   9
```

each of this variables inditates row with which it must be join in data1

here data1

```
      y1    y2

    `21     45
    q456    346
    q346    3q6
    yq      ewy
    wey     4e
    werer   yu
    ytu 256
    4323    62546u4
    ftyb    bynj
    dfgg    2335
    ye     4556
    1       2


V1 =1 must be joint with first row of y1
v2=1 must be joint with first row of y2
v1=3  must be joint with third row of y1
v2=5 must be joint with five row of y2
v1=4  must be joint with 4 row of y1
v2=8 must be joint with 8 row of y2
v1=7  must be joint with 7 row of y1
v2=9 must be joint with 9 row of y2
```

output

```
v1  v2  y1  y2
1   1   `21 45
3   5   q346    4e
4   8   yq  62546u4
7   9   ytu bynj
```

Comment: On this example, `data2$y1 <- data1$y1[data2$v1] ; data2$y2 <- data1$y2[data2$v2]` would work. But if you need something over multiple columns (y1, y999, v1, v999) you need to provide a better example.

Comment: @phiver, how be with multiple columns? I can't always do  it manually?

Comment: Maybe this is your desired output? `for(i in seq(ncol(data1)))
  data2[[names(data1)[i]]] <- data1[[i]][data2[[i]]]`

Comment: @Ryan, it returns null)   In 5 minites i ll edit post

Comment: @Ryan, please check edit. Is it understand

Comment: @phiver, i provided more data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `data2` contains row indices into `data1`. The OP wants to update `data2` by looking up the values of `y1` and `y2`, resp., in the rows given by `v1` and `v2` resp.

With `data.table` this can be solved by two different approaches

#### Lookup and update by reference

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data1)
setDT(data2)
data2[, y1 := data1[v1, y1]]
data2[, y2 := data1[v2, y2]]
data2
```

> ```
>    v1 v2   y1      y2
> 1:  1  1  `21      45
> 2:  3  5 q346      4e
> 3:  4  8   yq 62546u4
> 4:  7  9  ytu    bynj
> ```

#### Update join

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data2)[setDT(data1)[, rn := .I], on = .(v1 = rn), y1 := i.y1][
  data1, on = .(v2 = rn), y2 := i.y2]
data2
```

> ```
>    v1 v2   y1      y2
> 1:  1  1  `21      45
> 2:  3  5 q346      4e
> 3:  4  8   yq 62546u4
> 4:  7  9  ytu    bynj
> ```

Here, a helper column is appended to `data1` which contains the row indices to join on.

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
data2 <- fread("
v1  v2
1   1
3   5
4   8
7   9
")

data1 <- fread("
y1    y2
`21     45
q456    346
q346    3q6
yq      ewy
wey     4e
werer   yu
ytu 256
4323    62546u4
ftyb    bynj
dfgg    2335
ye     4556
1       2
")
```